# Protect Email with PHP - output is two words

Tags: php, email

This is my coding:

```
<?php
function protected_email($phpemail,$text='',$echo=true)
    {
        $pieces = explode("@", $phpemail);
        $return = '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = "<a href=\'mailto:";
        var b = "' . $pieces[0] . '";
        var c = "' . $pieces[1] .'";
        var d = "\' class=\'email\'>";
        var e = "</a>";';
        if($text != ''){
            $return .= 'document.write(a+b+"@"+c+d+\''.$text.'\'+e);';
        }else{
            $return .= 'document.write(a+b+"@"+c+d+b+"@"+c+e);';
        }
        $return .= '
            </script>
            <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view emails</noscript>';
        if($echo == true)
        {
            echo $return;
        }else{
            return $return;
        }
    }
?>

<?php echo protected_email('change@email.com', Their Title); ?>
```

I want to display the person's title instead of their email address, but I cannot get both words to show in their title, unless I remove the space between.  How do I get it to dsiplay both words?

Display this:
**Their Title**

Rather display than:
**change@email.com**

I'm sure it is something really simple, but I am at a mental block right now.

Comment: That last line looks like a syntax error...

Comment: `Their Title` or `'Their Title'`? In PHP, string values must be quoted, otherwise they are treated as constants

Comment: You may want to consider using: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey

Comment: I can't see how a space in the title would affect the output. Show the js/html code that's generated by this PHP, specifically a sample that causes  your problem.

Comment: @MarkBaker - Thank you.  I just realized I totally forgot to add the quotes.  That is the answer I needed that was staring me right in the face.  Leave it to me to try to over-complicate.